# Apache: Map (sub)domain to directories without changing documentroot

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

I got the documentroot set up like this: var/www/html

What I'm trying to do is:

cms.domain.com --> var/www/html/cms

domain.com --> var/www/html/cms/sites/site1

I'm trying to accomplish this by using virtualhosts. The problem is I can't set a VirtualDocumentRoot for each (sub)domain because the sites use a bunch of scripts and configs, located in var/www/html/includes which are supposed to stay non public, and the apps call these with $_SERVER["document_root"].

What I've tried is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    AliasMatch ^(.*)$ /cms/sites/site1/

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

and for the subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>      
    ServerName cms.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.cms.domain.com

    AliasMatch ^(.*)$ /cms/

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
    </IfModule>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Doesn't work. I guess what I'm actually looking for is something to append the path after documentroot while keeping documentroot how it is.

Comment: It could be helpful to the reader to know what "Doesn't work" means. Where does apache pick the html files up from, when you `GET` cms.domain.com or respectively domain.com?

Comment: One problem could be that cms.domain.com (2nd VirtualHost) is a subset of *.domain.com (first VirtualHost). So without studying the apache docu in detail, I can't say if apache will apply the 1st or the 2nd VirtualHost config, if you do a `GET` cms.domain.com.

Comment: directories which are supposed to be "non-public" should never be in documentroot. Use ScriptAlias or similar to link to those.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of conflicting configuration here. I would suggest creating a `VirtualHost` for `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` and another for `*.domain.com` and/or *.cms.domain.com with the `AliasMatch`. There is also precedence in `VirtualHosts` so domain.com should be last.

The easiest way out of the common config issue is to symlink `/var/www/html/includes` to each `VirtualHost` directory and then you at least have consistency.